# Character Dialogue Asset Management

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, assets

Just working on a class that deals with sound files in ActionScript for my Starling project. I would like your opinions on the implementation and whether it would perform well. (This file will be getting huge with embedded files).

This is another thing, if it is embedded, is this a bad thing? I mean if I embedded so many voice files, even though they weren't going to be used would this affect performance?

Anyway here is my implementation:

```
package assets 
{
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.media.SoundTransform;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Shaun Stone
     */
    public class CharacterDialogueSoundAssets 
    {
        // This will return the voice file is exists
        private static var _soundAssetsDictionary:Dictionary= new Dictionary();

        [Embed(source = "../../../media/sounds/dialogue/voice_file_1.mp3")]
        public static const VOICE_FILE_1:Class;

        /**
         * Get voice file from dictionary
         * 
         * @param   name
         * @return
         */
        public static function getVoiceFile(name:String):Sound 
        {
            if (_soundAssetsDictionary[name] == undefined)
            {
                var voiceFile:Sound = new CharacterDialogueSoundAssets.name() as     Sound;
                _soundAssetsDictionary[name] = voiceFile;
            }

            return _soundAssetsDictionary[name];
        }

        public static function disposeOfVoiceFile(name:String):void 
        {
            if (_soundAssetsDictionary[name] == undefined)
            {
                return;
            }

            //dispose for garbage collection
            _soundAssetsDictionary[name] = undefined;
        }
      }
    }
```